# Writing my own wifi driver for linux?

Tags: wifi, wifimanager

I am wondering where to start if I decided to write\hack my own wifi driver?
What language should be of choice? 
Where to get the initial research documents? Fourms I should visit? IRC channels?

Comment: Go to work for a chip maker and steal the specs.  Many aren't public.

Comment: Why would you want to write your own driver? If it is to support a wireless chip that is not yet supported in Linux, getting the hardware description (datasheet) is both inevitable and nearly impossible because most vendors will not disclose it. If it is for learning, I would recommend to start with a well-supported chip and re-implement the driver. You can use the existing code to develop a specification from that or ask the developers about their sources of information. Maybe leaked datasheets exist.